# Difference between "parameter" and "localparam"

Tags: verilog

I'm writing a project with Verilog and want to use `parameter` to define some parameter in my module. But when I read in some source code, `localparam` sometimes is used instead of `parameter`.

What's difference between them?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Generally, the idea behind the `localparam` (added to the Verilog-2001 standard) is to protect value of `localparam` from accidental or incorrect redefinition by an end-user (unlike a `parameter` value, this value can't be modified by parameter redefinition or by a `defparam` statement).

Based on IEEE 1364-2005 (ch. 4.10.2):

> **Verilog HDL local parameters are identical to parameters except that they cannot directly be modified by defparam statements or module instance parameter value assignments**. Local parameters can be assigned constant expressions containing parameters, which can be modified with defparam statements or module instance parameter value assignments.

Additionally, in SystemVerilog ([IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) (ch. 6.20.4)):

> Unlike nonlocal parameters, local parameters can be declared in a generate block, package, class body, or compilation-unit scope. In these contexts, the parameter keyword shall be a synonym for the localparam keyword.
> Local parameters may be declared in a module’s parameter_port_list. Any parameter declaration appearing in such a list between a localparam keyword and the next parameter keyword (or the end of the list, if there is no next parameter keyword) shall be a local parameter. Any other parameter declaration in such a list shall be a nonlocal parameter that may be overridden.

If you want to learn more about this topic, I'd recommend you Clifford E. Cummings paper "[New Verilog-2001 Techniques for Creating Parameterized Models (or Down With `define and Death of a defparam!)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-884-complex-digital-systems-spring-2005/resources/parameter_models/)".

Answer (score 14):

**Minimal example**

Here is an example of what Qiu mentioned.

In a RAM, the memory size is a function of the word and address sizes.

So if the parent module specifies word and address size, it should not be able to specify the memory size as well.

```
module myram #(
    parameter WORD_SIZE = 1,
    parameter ADDR_SIZE = 1
) (
    input wire [ADDR_SIZE-1:0] addr,
    inout wire [WORD_SIZE-1:0] data,
    // ...
);
    localparam MEM_SIZE = WORD_SIZE * (1 << ADDR_SIZE);
    // Use MEM_SIZE several times in block.
...
```

And on parent module, this is fine:

```
module myram_tb;
    myram #(
        .ADDR_SIZE(2),
        .WORD_SIZE(2)
    ) top (
        /* wires */
    )
```

but this *should* be an error:

```
module myram_tb;
    myram #(
        .ADDR_SIZE(2),
        .WORD_SIZE(2),
        .MEM_SIZE(2)
    ) top (
        /* wires */
    )
```

<strike>`iverilog` doesn't fail, and I believe that this is a bug: https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog/issues/157</strike>

Incisive gives an error as expected.